# Program works, but jar is unable to launch due to signature file

Tags: java, jar, manifest

My program works fine once it's compiled on the IDE, but when I try to run the .jar that's created, I get the following error:

```
java -jar /Users/bigbitecode/Documents/workspace/sys\ client_b/sys-client/out/artifacts/sys_client_jar/sys-client.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: no manifiest section for signature file entry com/sun/java/help/impl/TagProperties.class
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.verifySection(SignatureFileVerifier.java:399)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:250)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:193)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:305)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:216)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:345)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:412)
    at sun.misc.JarIndex.getJarIndex(JarIndex.java:137)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:668)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:659)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:632)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:362)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:352)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:351)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:328)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:194)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I've read through a couple similar questions, and it seems to be caused due to an offending jar I'm using as a dependency, but I have no idea which one or how I can find it. Once I do, however, how do I exclude it from the jar?

Would it be a cause of intelliJ? Is it possible to build the jar via terminal?

EDIT:
 - I have done a jar -tf sys-client.jar and it reveals all the files, incl the manifest.
 - Currently my manifest has the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: SysClient.data.gui.SysClient
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can build a jar file from terminal using jar command. Refer to this doc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Make sure that manifest is set properly. Also once the jar is created, run jar -tf and check if all the classes and manifest file is present or not.

Would it be a cause of intelliJ: looks like your jar is not bundled properly. If you want, you can first verify if content of the jar file are proper using jar -tf jar-fileName.jar

Comment: I tried jar -tf jar-fileName.jar made from intelliJ and grepped the manifest, sure enough it's there. Same error, however.

Comment: It's kinda long... here's an access to an instantserver with my output.txt (don't worry, it's not my actual server)

Username: ubuntu, Password: Q1dDwJur

//FYI, it'll only last for 30 min from now.
ssh ubuntu@174.129.113.221

Comment: i need access to two more things, one is TagProperties.class(.java) and META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Comment: I don't know how to access (don't know where it's located) TagProperies.java and my question has the texts inside manifest.mf

Comment: I just found it: I've uploaded it to the server again with new credentials: Username: ubuntu, Password: NRhsppCE
ssh ubuntu@54.226.108.206